# how to add certain number of blank colums to the right of html table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I am generating a table using json data with jquery, which has only two columns with data. I am trying to add 10 more blank columns to the right of the generated table without even a column heading. Below is the code to populate the table with json data:

```
function populateTable(result) {
        $("#mytable").empty();
        result = jQuery.parseJSON(result.d);
        var keys = Object.keys(result[0]);
        var row = $('<tr></tr>').appendTo("#mytable");
        $.each(keys, function (i, item) {
            $('<th></th>').text(item).appendTo(row);
        });

        $.each(result, function (i, item) {
            var row = $('<tr></tr>').appendTo("#mytable");
            $.each(keys, function (i, key) {
                $('<td></td>').text(item[key]).appendTo(row);
            });
        });
    }
```

I have tried this so far:

```
for(var i=0;i=10;1++){$('table').find('tr').each(function(){$(this).prepend('<td></td>'); });});
```

It doesn't work. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `columns` is rendering or not? you can check with `Inspect Element`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[.prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) will insert element at start use [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) instead to insert on right.

Further there is serious issue within what you have tried. within for loop condition you have `i=10` that will always returns true and loop will become infinite loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    $('table').find('tr').each(function() {
        $(this).append('<td></td>');
    });
}
```

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    $('table').find('tr').each(function() {
        $(this).append('<td></td>');
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>


<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `i=10` will always evaluate to `true` because it's an assignment;

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am able to get it now.

Comment: There is on more query how do I make the first element of each column as  <th> as I have applied background color on <th> element .Using this I am getting all <td>.

Comment: `$('table').find('tr').first().find("td").each(function () {
    var that = $(this);
    that.replaceWith('<th>' + that.html() +'</th>');
});`

Answer (score 0):

Just place  &nbsp; inside td or th

Answer (score 0):

you should add `&nbsp` inside like `<td>&nbsp;</td>`